# Create SOAP webservice client in java

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, qlikview, wsimport

I am trying to use wsimport to create client for a soap webservice. however it throws an error as below. How can i force it to generate. I can call the services just fine in SOAP UI but could not generate the client because of this error. I tried Eclipse with Axis as option to generate the client, it generates but does not generate Object factory class.

I cannot change the XSD as it is a COTS product ( or can I?)

```
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:schema'.
It was detected that 'xs:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 
but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'http://<<IP>>:4799/QMS/Service?xsd=xsd11'. 
If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:schema' needs to be changed. 
If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'http://<<IP>>:4799/QMS/Service?xsd=xsd11'.
line 1 of http://<<IP>>:4799/QMS/Service?xsd=xsd11

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:schema' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
line 1 of http://<<IP>>:4799/QMS/Service?xsd=xsd11

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'
line 1 of http://<<IP>>:4799/QMS/Service?xsd=xsd11

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

Comment: How is this question related to qlikview?
anyways - to run WSDL from qlik, the best way I found is to run external command "curl". check "WSDL from curl" in google

Comment: That is a qlikview service i am using.